# how to get callback value from cameratag in controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to get callback value from [cameratag](https://cameratag.com/) in controller rails?

How to use below code in controller rails in [tutorial server callback](https://cameratag.com/docs/setup#callback)?

```
data = JSON.parse(request.raw_post)
video_uuid = data["uuid"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a HTTPpost request with the required parameters as given in the link https://cameratag.com/docs/setup#callback . Then from the response you need to execute the data line. EX :

```
data_map =     {
  "uuid": "6611a310-72c4-0130-04c5-123139045d73",
  "camera_uuid": "63f9c870-72c4-0130-04c5-123139045d73",
  "created_at": "2013-03-19T13:11:13Z",
  "percent_complete": 0,
  "short_code": null,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "state": "published",
  "recorded_from": "https://cameratag.com/",
  "publish_type": null,
  "formats": [
    {
      "name": "360p",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360,
      "video_url": "http://cameratag.com/videos/6611a310-72c4-0130-04c5-123139045d73/360p/mp4",
      "mp4_url": "http://cameratag.com/videos/6611a310-72c4-0130-04c5-123139045d73/360p/mp4",
      "webm_url": "http://cameratag.com/videos/6611a310-72c4-0130-04c5-123139045d73/360p/webm",
      "thumbnail_url": "http://cameratag.com/videos/6611a310-72c4-0130-04c5-    123139045d73/360p/thumb",
      "small_thumbnail_url": "http://cameratag.com/videos/6611a310-72c4-0130-04c5-    123139045d73/360p/small_thumb",
      "state": "COMPLETED",
      "completed_at": null
    }
  ]
}
path = -- give the path for the post request.
http = Net::HTTP.new('site-name.com')
resp = http.post(path,data_map)
data = JSON.parse(resp) 
video_uuid = data["uuid"]
```

There are many other ways to make a post request. The point is you need to use JSON.parse() on the response of the post request and then get the uuid.

Comment: What i gave you is the controller code. You need to get the entries for the data variables from view as form parameters and post it to a controller method where you can make the post call to the respective website with the above controller code.

Am sorry but its not possible for me to give you out the entire implementation and code from the view and controller.